# Physics with balls in Java, Energy not working

Tags: java, physics

When balls bounce elastically and without drag the total energy of that ball (kinetic + potential) should remain the same at all times.
I have created a graph to find out if it was working correctly and it didn't. Instead it looks like this.
[image: graph]

The last 4 or 5 dots should be ignored, those are old data (8 seconds ago). The graph restarts at the front when it gets to the back.

White is the total energy, cyan is kinetic and green is potential.

The formulas for the calculation of the energy:

```
double tempv = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vx, 2) + Math.pow(vy, 2));
double h = (600 + -y + 53 - (0.5 * size)) / 100;
eKin = 0.5 * m * Math.pow(tempv, 2);
ePot = m * g * h;
eTot = eKin + ePot;
```

The formulas for forces etc.

```
    double Fzw = g * m;
    double Fb = rho * V * g;
    Fd = 0;//0.5 * rho * Math.pow(vy, 2) * Cd * A;

    if (vy > 0)
    {
        Fres = Fzw - Fd - Fb;
    }
    else
    {
        Fres = Fzw + Fd - Fb;
    }

    a = Fres / m;


    vy += a * Main.dt;
```

The formulas and all the other code I'm using for this can be found over here: https://github.com/wuppy29/PWS/tree/master/src/com/wuppy/pws/src

I have tried to find out what was wrong, but I have no clue why it wouldn't work. Does anybody have an idea?

The program: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59067404/Balls.jar

Comment: Could you add the relevant parts of the code to the question?

Comment: All of the relevant code should be in there now.

Comment: This is not a debugging service. And I have always regarded physics highly... no need to qualify it

Comment: By the way I love the title. Physics with balls. It certainly made me smile.

Comment: *"All of the relevant code.."*  Until you know the problem, what is and is not relevant is not easy to determine.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Haha, didn't even notice that. I will upload an SSCCE right now.

Answer (score 0):

Just from looking at the graph, I can tell that you are using different scales for potential and kinetic energy. They should be mirror images of each other.

Comment: Then I must be calculating one of the energies wrong, because all of the 3 energies are using the same scale in the graph.

Comment: Only you could possibly answer a question like that. What is the total energy of the system?

Comment: When there is only a single ball in the window (not visible in the image) which there was when I took this picture the total energy is between 1.3 and 2.3 J.

Comment: As long as the area of both curves are equal it should be fine, it just means the kinetic energy behaves differently over time.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [forward euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) to interpolate the new positions, it is the least accurate way of interpolation, the error just propogates over time. You might consider something like [Runge Kutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods). I see no other problem with the code you have shown us.